# SwiftUI Font - Is there a way to create Serif type Font without requiring UIFont to Font conversion?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

Currently, this is how I create Serif type SwiftUI font.

```
let textSize = 20

let sfFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: textSize)

let fontDescriptor = sfFont.fontDescriptor

if let newYorkFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.withDesign(.serif) {
    let newYorkFont = UIFont(descriptor: newYorkFontDescriptor, size: 0.0)

    return Font(newYorkFont)
} else {
    return Font(sfFont)
}
```

I was wondering, is there a way without having to perform `UIFont` to `Font` conversion, to improve code efficiency?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure *this* is the performance bottleneck? I am almost certain that changing this will not make a noticeable difference in terms of *efficiency*...

Comment: That said, surely you would have found [`Font.Design.serif`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/design/serif)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`system(size:weight:design:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/system(size:weight:design:)-697b2) or [`system(_:design:weight:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/system(_:design:weight:)).

```
Text("Hello, world!")
    .font(.system(size: 20, design: .serif))
```